# Does form data with no "name" element get sent across the internet?

Tags: forms, input

I am asking this question from a *security* standpoint. If I have an input field with no name element, I know it is not *processed* by the server, but is it *sent across the internet*? I have seen several different answers on this and I am wondering if we can get a definitive answer established.

Also, is there a way to *explicitly* prevent an input field from being sent with the form data while not disabling it?

Comment: I suppose I could delete fields from the form before submitting. Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an ingenious workaround here. Just create a second form and "steal" the protected data so it is not submitted:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

However, I'd still like answer to the original question. Plus this may only work in HTML5, leaving a security vulnerability for people using older browsers.